# Индекс 6 находиться вне диапазона

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь сделать сортировку элементов и он крашится, искал в интернете,но ошибки, которые показывают у меня нет.

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{

const int number = 6;
char str[number] = { 'z','x','с','v','b','\0' };
char temp;
int a, b;
for (int i = 0; i < number;i++)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < number; j++)
    {
        a = (str[j]);
        b = (str[j + 1]);
        if (a > b)
        {
            temp = str[j];
            str[j] = str[j + 1];
            str[j + 1] = temp;

        }
    }
        

    
}
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    cout << str[i] << " ";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Индекс 6 находиться вне диапазона ... ошибки, которые показывают у меня нет`. А если `j == number - 1`, то к какому элементу массива происходит обращение вот здесь: `str[j + 1]`?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка, как и написал wololo - у вас выход за пределы массива при `j==5` в операции `b = (str[j + 1])`. Т.е. внутренний цикл должен быть `for( ; j < number-1; )`
Ещё одна возможная логическая ошибка - вы сортируете по возрастанию символьный массив. А в нем символ `\0` является специальным (служебным) - обозначающим конец строки в стандарте `c`, а не значимым символом этой строки. Вряд ли логически он должен участвовать в сортировке. И если вы попытаетесь после сортировки вывести массив как строку `cout << str;` - то ноль на первом месте закончит вывод так и не начав его.
А ещё вашу пузырьковую сортировку можно немного улучшить. Сейчас вы делаете `n*n` операций.
При каждом выполнении внутреннего цикла у вас максимальный элемент в массиве перемещается на последнее место. Поэтому на следующем шаге его можно больше не сравнивать. Для этого внешний цикл нужно сделать на убывание, а условие внутреннего цикла - до `i`.

```
int main()
{
    const int number = 6;
    char str[number] = { "zxcvb" };
    int size = number - 1; // убираем служебный 0 из сортировки

    cout << str << endl; // вывод строки до сортировки

    for (int i = size-1; i > 0; i--)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (str[j] > str[j + 1])
                swap( str[j], str[j + 1] );

    cout << str << endl; // вывод строки после сортировки
}
```

Comment: Используйте sizeof(str), тогда не надо ни какое size-1

Comment: @Виктор `sizeof(str)` как раз выдаст 6. Можно использовать `strlen(str)`, тогда получится размер строки без завершающего 0.